# I am not able to delete a specific item from a table in Django template/view got a valueError like Field 'id' expected a number but got 'Btc'

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-views, django-templates, foreign-keys

I have a list of wallet addresses in my template. When I tried deleting an address by clicking on the delete button, it returns an error message. I think it is an error from the way my template was structured. But, I don't really know. When I try deleting an address by manually inputting the id of the address in the delete view URL, it gets deleted.
Here is the error message that is returned.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\admin\Documents\Django\env\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\__init__.py", line 2018, in get_prep_value
    return int(value)

The above exception (invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'Btc') was the direct cause of the following exception:
  File "C:\Users\admin\Documents\Django\env\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 55, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "C:\Users\admin\Documents\Django\env\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 197, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\admin\Documents\Django\env\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\decorators.py", line 23, in _wrapped_view
    return view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\admin\Documents\Django\crypto\dashboard\views.py", line 275, in del_wallet
    wallet.delete()
  File "C:\Users\admin\Documents\Django\env\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 1137, in delete
    return collector.delete()
  File "C:\Users\admin\Documents\Django\env\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\deletion.py", line 475, in delete
    query.update_batch(
  File "C:\Users\admin\Documents\Django\env\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\subqueries.py", line 78, in update_batch
    self.get_compiler(using).execute_sql(NO_RESULTS)
  File "C:\Users\admin\Documents\Django\env\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\compiler.py", line 1819, in execute_sql
    cursor = super().execute_sql(result_type)
  File "C:\Users\admin\Documents\Django\env\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\compiler.py", line 1382, in execute_sql
    sql, params = self.as_sql()
  File "C:\Users\admin\Documents\Django\env\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\compiler.py", line 1785, in as_sql
    val = field.get_db_prep_save(val, connection=self.connection)
  File "C:\Users\admin\Documents\Django\env\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\related.py", line 1146, in get_db_prep_save
    return self.target_field.get_db_prep_save(value, connection=connection)
  File "C:\Users\admin\Documents\Django\env\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\__init__.py", line 925, in get_db_prep_save
    return self.get_db_prep_value(value, connection=connection, prepared=False)
  File "C:\Users\admin\Documents\Django\env\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\__init__.py", line 2703, in get_db_prep_value
    value = self.get_prep_value(value)
  File "C:\Users\admin\Documents\Django\env\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\__init__.py", line 2020, in get_prep_value
    raise e.__class__(

Exception Type: ValueError at /dashboard/wallet/2/delete/
Exception Value: Field 'id' expected a number but got 'Btc'.
```

views.py

```
@login_required
def wallet(request):
    user = request.user
    wallet=Wallet(user=user)
    object_list = Wallet.objects.filter(user=user)
    # Paginator
    paginator = Paginator(object_list, 2) 
    page = request.GET.get('page')
    try:
        ref = paginator.page(page)
    except PageNotAnInteger:
        ref = paginator.page(1)
    except EmptyPage:
        ref = paginator.page(paginator.num_pages)    
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if 'add' in request.POST:
            form = WalletForm(request.POST, instance=wallet)
            if form.is_valid():
                form.save()
                messages.success(request, ("New wallet address successfully added."))
                return redirect("dashboard:wallet")
    else:
        form = WalletForm(instance=user)
    context = {
        'form': form,
        'ref': ref,
        # 'refe': refe
        # 'del_wallet': del_wallet
    }
    return render(request, 'dashboard/wallet.html', context)


@login_required
def del_wallet(request, pk):
    wallet = get_object_or_404(Wallet, id=pk)
    wallet.delete()
    return redirect("dashboard:wallet")
```

The first view `wallet` is responsible for letting users add new wallet, and also responsible for displaying the wallets. The adding wallet logic is done by the use of a popup modal.
The second view `del_wallet` is responsible for handling the delete logic.

urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('wallet', wallet, name="wallet"),
    path('wallet/<str:pk>/delete/', del_wallet, name="del_wallet"),
]
```

By typing out the URL and specifying an id, the wallet address with the id gets deleted. Like, calling *http://localhost"5000/wallet/2/delete/* deletes the address with id of 2. But clicking on the delete button attached to each wallet, returns back the error message specified above. I added print statement to check the details of the wallet that pops up each time I click the delete button. It logs the correct wallet being clicked with its id, but yet it returns an error message. I can't seem to figure out what is causing the error.

wallet.html

```
<h3 class="h5 text-primary pt-1 pt-lg-3 mt-4">Available Wallets</h3>
            <div class="table-responsive">
                <table class="table table-dark table-striped">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                        <th>SN</th>
                        <th>Type</th>
                        <th>Address</th>
                        <th>Delete</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        <!--  -->
                        {% for i in ref %}
                            <tr>
                                <td style="line-height: 1.3; padding-top: 1.6em;">{{ forloop.counter }}</td>
                                <td style="padding-top: 20px;">{{ i.get_type_display }}</td>
                                <td style="padding-top: 20px;">{{ i.address }}</td>
                                <td class="view" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#wallet{{ i.pk }}">
                                    <a style="text-decoration: none;" href="#wallet{{ i.pk }}">
                                        Delete
                                    </a>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <!-- DELETE MODAL -->
                            <div class="modal fade" id="wallet{{ i.pk }}" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" style="margin-top: 10em;">
                                <div class="modal-dialog modal-sm" role="document">
                                    <div class="modal-content" style="background: #141822;">
                                        <div class="modal-body">
                                            <h6>Confirm Delete</h6>
                                            <p>Are you sure you want to delete 
                                                <span style="color: rgb(10, 223, 165);">
                                                    {{ i.type }} - {{ i.address }}
                                                </span> wallet?
                                            </p>
                                                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm w-100">
                                                    <a href="/dashboard/wallet/{{ i.pk }}/delete/" style="text-decoration: none;">
                                                        Confirm
                                                    </a>
                                                </button><br>
                                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning btn-sm w-100 mt-2" data-bs-dismiss="modal">
                                                   Close
                                                </button>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        {% empty %}
                            <tr>
                                <td>You haven't added a wallet address yet.</td>
                                <td></td>
                                <td></td>
                                <td></td>
                            </tr>
                        {% endfor %}
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
```

models.py

```
class Wallet(models.Model):
    wallet = (
        ('Btc', 'Bitcoin'), 
        ('Eth', 'Ethereum'), 
        ('Trc20', 'Tether-UDST'), 
        ('Ltc', 'Litecoin') 
)
    user = models.ForeignKey(get_user_model(), on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    type = models.CharField(choices=wallet, default='Btc') 
    address = models.CharField(max_length=80)
```

Please, what is likely the cause of the error. I've read up many posts online, but none seems to help in resolving my problem.

Comment: Plz add wallet model code in question

Comment: I have added my models.py file. Thanks

Comment: I think u need to be change name of type field because type is reserved keyword in python
If still got un error then message me

Comment: Alright.. I will try that right away

Comment: I still got the same error. I can only delete by manually inputting the ID of the wallet to the url, but not via the delete button.

Comment: Print pk it's returns id or Btc in delete view

Comment: It returns the ID

Answer (score 1):

At first it should be `<int:pk>` not `<str:pk>` and secondly use url tags in anchor tags so:

```html
<a href="{% url 'dashboard:del_wallet' i.pk %}" style="text-decoration: none;">
```

It's better to change the url as:

```py
urlpatterns = [
    path('wallet/', wallet, name="wallet"),
    path('wallet/delete/<int:pk>/', del_wallet, name="del_wallet"),
]
```

> **Note:** Always add `/` at the end of every route.

Comment: Thanks for the corrections. I've implemented the changes you mentioned. It did help clean up my work. But the error pertaining to the delete logic is still coming up.

Comment: @Buchii you can share you repo if possible, so I will reply you soon.

Answer (score 1):

```
<td class="view" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#wallet{{ i.pk }}">
    <a style="text-decoration: none;" href="{% url 'del_wallet' i.pk %}">
        Delete
    </a>
</td>
```

#### only take link like this

```
<a href="{% url 'del_wallet' i.pk %}" style="text-decoration: none;">
    Confirm
</a>
```

#### Remove this

```
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm w-100">
</button>
```